# How is pipelined DES different from sequential DES?

Tags: architecture

I implemented DES (Data Encryption Standard) Coder in VHDL using ISE IDE by Xilinx in sequential architecture which was pretty easy and straightforward. Now my task is to do the same using pipelined architecture so that the whole thing will work with maximum possible clock frequency. I read numerous papers from IEEE site concerning pipelined DES but still I couldn't fully get my head around the topic. What is different? So far I understood that I have to make it so:

There are no complex instructions in the code of every module. For example if I had instruction "x <= a * b * c" I'd have to break it down to two instructions in for loop and when iterator is equal to 0 do "temp <= a * b" and when iterator is equal 1 do "x <= temp * c". Just an example but shows the way of thinking - instead of one complex instructions - many simple ones (using loops or for generate).

Once input A gets to Feistel Round 2 then input B (for example next 64-bit plaintext word) gets loaded immediately to Feistel Round 1 and so on allowing us to process 16 words "quasi simultaneously". That would require us to have a synchronizing register before and after every Feistel Function module. Also I read something about modules for "pipeline" and "control module" although none of the articles mentioned how they worked. To be honest I have zero ideas about how to implement this part.

Are my presumptions wrong at any of the 2 points? Could anyone please explain to me in detail how to bite into this problem? Does anyone have an example of working pipelined DES Coder/Decoder on FPGA? I will be thankful for every bit of help.

Comment: Loosely related: DES is broken. Don't use it.

Comment: Best to use 2Fish. Even though NSA ranked it badly as 2nd best

Comment: Well, the industry standard is AES, which is currently Rijndael ...

Comment: To be honest I don't intend to use it. It's just my University project. I'm interested in programming FPGA's, VHDL, Cryptography and Cryptanalysis so my professor suggested me to do this as my project. I was also suggesting AES but this idea got dismissed due to it being too complicated at my stage (2nd year of Uni) and that I should leave it to my thesis.

Comment: I don't think there is much of complexity difference between DES and AES... Anyway, that's not your question.

Comment: It is not quite clear from your question, but I imagine that in the current sequential implementation, you have only one feistel block. You have a counter from 0 to 15, and go through the same feistel 16 time to cipher each block (you currently need 16 cycles to process a block). Then a possible pipelining evolution is to have 16 feistel blocks in sequence and make each block traverse this pipeline. So you can process 16 blocks (each at a different position in the pipeline) simultaneously and cipher one block per cycle... Unless this is what you have already. Please clarify.

Comment: This is what I got already: I have 16 feistel rounds in sequence one after the other, but I only have registers at the input and output of the whole schematic. So currently I have no control module that would allow me to "pump" another set of data once current data hops into second Feistel block leaving first empty. To be honest I don't really know how to implement such control module correctly.

Comment: Then, you just need to infer registers between each stage. There is no need for a "control module" as you seem to believe. You did most of the work already, and there is very few differences between both versions. I'm sorry, I can't write a proper answer (I'm trying to get some sleep). Anyway, you should post your code. Maybe not all the details, but at least the top-level where you instantiate 16 times the feistel rounds.

Comment: To be honest the code for each and every module is pretty simple. Just some permutation with for generate. What will tell you more are my RTL schematics. I will upload them and also code for my synchronizing register.

Comment: The paper is *Hardware Implementation of DES Using Pipelining Concept with Time-Variable Key* from the 22nd International Conference on Microelectronics (ICM2010) by 3 members of Electrical Engineering Dept at Minia University, Egypt. Tinkering with the key schedule seems fraught with risk.

Comment: See the [pipelined_des](https://github.com/diogratia/pipelined_des) model on Github for  an example synthesis eligible VHDL model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a series implementation puts all the data through each stage and you have towait for the output to settle before you can use it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flTZip.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with a pipelined implementation there's a register between each stage so that after the first stage has processed the block it's output can be stored in the register and the second block can enter the pipeline. in this way at the expens of some latency throughput can be increased manyfold.

The reason why the lower pipelined implementation is faster is because the first stage can only be clocked as fast as the inverse of the propagation delay of F1-F4 cascaded. If F1-F4 takes super long to compute, then you can't pump a lot of data through it.

The pipedlined datapath can be clocked as fast as the worst of the propagation delays of the stages allow it to. That means, assuming F1-F4 have the same propagation delay, you can pump 4x more data through.

Comment: Thank you for Your answer. I think this is what I did (I just edited my post) but I will have to wait till October to test it on FPGA.